# Can I use an SMTP server behind a firewall when using Gmail?

Tags: gmail, smtp

I use a certain email address with Gmail, and I would like to use for it a different SMTP server than the normal one (it is an alias). The SMTP server is behind a firewall, is it still possible to use it from the Gmail web client when I am on the allowed network for the firewall? Or is it the case that the email is routed through Google's network into the SMTP server? If so, what are my options?

Comment: it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: It depends on the Firewall setup. Does it allow connections from the Google servers? Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/95251/88163

Comment: @Ruben no, it doesn't.

Comment: @Ruben could it be that in that email the poster had the same issue because his institution put their SMTP server behind a firewall? Is GMail (web) sending the email through the assigned SMTP server from the browser client or through their own servers? I imagine the latter.

Comment: Regarding your options, IMHO, the best will be to ask to the administrador of your email account.